# Martix of Counts of Regex Hits Over a List of Strings

Tags: python, beginner, regex, pandas

I have:

- A dataframe with Identifiers (`TermId`) and Search Terms (`SearchTerm`).
- A list of text strings (`MyText`).  This likely would be a column (series) in a dataframe.

I for every string in `MyText` I want to get a count of hits for every regex `SearchTerm`, producing a table of counts.  This is a scaled down example.  I'd have 10,000 of `Mytext` and 100s of `SearchTerm`s.  I am newer to Python (from R) and would like to know where can I optimize the code to make it more performant?  I'm open to what ever feedback people have to offer on all aspects of the code.

```
## Dependencies
import re
import pandas as pd

## Data
MyText = ['I saw xx.yy and also xx.yyy', 'FireFly* this is xx_yy there', 'I xx$YY', 'I see x.yy now .NET', 'now xx.yyxx.yyxx.yy']
 
MyDictionary = pd.DataFrame({
    'TermId': ['SK_{}'.format(x) for x in list(range(0, 6))],
    'SearchTerm': ['xx[.]yy', '[.]NET', 'A[+]', 'FireFly[*]', 'NetFlix[$]',  'Adobe[*]']
})


## Convert Search Term to Compiled Regex Object
MyDictionary['Regexes'] = [re.compile(s) for s in MyDictionary['SearchTerm']]

## List comprehension to double loop over the regexes &  
## elements of MyText to count hits
out = {id: [len(regex.findall(s)) for s in MyText] for regex, id in zip(MyDictionary['Regexes'], MyDictionary['TermId'])}
out = pd.DataFrame(out)
out['MyText'] = MyText

## Results
print(out)
print(MyDictionary)
```

Which yields:

```
   SK_0  SK_1  SK_2  SK_3  SK_4  SK_5                        MyText
0     2     0     0     0     0     0   I saw xx.yy and also xx.yyy
1     0     0     0     1     0     0  FireFly* this is xx_yy there
2     0     0     0     0     0     0                       I xx$YY
3     0     1     0     0     0     0           I see x.yy now .NET
4     3     0     0     0     0     0           now xx.yyxx.yyxx.yy
```

Answer (score 2):

An idiomatic approach would be to put `MyText` in a dataframe (if not already) and [**`assign()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the results of [**`str.count()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html).

I'd also suggest using an actual `dict` for the regex mapping. It's not strictly necessary, but the syntax is just cleaner given that this use case aligns with `dict`. (Here I created `terms` from `MyDictionary` just for continuity with the existing code.)

````py
terms = dict(zip(MyDictionary.TermId, MyDictionary.SearchTerm))
df = pd.DataFrame({'MyText': MyText})

df = df.assign(**{key: df.MyText.str.count(val) for key, val in terms.items()})

#                          MyText  SK_0  SK_1  SK_2  SK_3  SK_4  SK_5
# 0   I saw xx.yy and also xx.yyy     2     0     0     0     0     0
# 1  FireFly* this is xx_yy there     0     0     0     1     0     0
# 2                       I xx$YY     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 3           I see x.yy now .NET     0     1     0     0     0     0
# 4           now xx.yyxx.yyxx.yy     3     0     0     0     0     0
```
````